# Can't figure out how eclipse plugin is determining renaming choices

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I posted the following note in the Eclipse forums: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1072029/ .  This has all the details, but I'll repeat them here.

I'm working with a somewhat complex Eclipse plugin codebase. It's used for the purpose of editing files in a specific language. I'm pretty new to maintaining Eclipse plugins. The original authors are not easily available.

The codebase is open-source, and it's on github at https://github.com/xored/yang-ide .

The language the plugin is for has some similarities to XML (not in the syntax), in that one module can "import" another by name, and specify a prefix to be associated with the symbols from that imported file. The language also has a "use" command, which takes a symbol name that represents sort of a structured type. The symbol name can be with or without a prefix. The structured type can be defined in that module, or in an imported module.

The plugin has a feature whereby I can select the definition of a symbol name and select "Rename" in the "Refactoring" submenu. It will select all the occurrences of that symbol name in the file and prompt me to rename it, just like how the Java editor (and others) work.

The problem is, some of the occurrences it chooses to replace might not be valid. If I selected a symbol name in that module that happens to be the same name as a symbol in an imported module, which is referenced by a prefix in this module, when I select the "Rename" operation, it will mark those prefixed occurrences also, even though they refer to a different symbol.

What's befuddling me is that even though I have full access to the source code of this plugin, I can't figure out where it's determining which symbols to select. I did find a [`RenameAction`](https://github.com/xored/yang-ide/blob/7cab25b5ff8ce71e5b33b68b692dfb386404f995/plugins/com.cisco.yangide.ext.refactoring/src/com/cisco/yangide/ext/refactoring/actions/RenameAction.java) class, which extends Action and implements `ISelectionChangedListener`, but nothing in there appears to have this logic. I imagine there must be something "inherent" in what this is doing, such that the logic is already provided in the SDK, I just don't see where this comes in.

I was able to set up a remote debugging system, connecting to an Eclipse test instance running in a VM, from the Eclipse instance on the host, so I won't have any issues stepping through event-driven code.

I could use any ideas for tracking this kind of issue in Eclipse plugins. I imagine there are other plugins with similar behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the action just collections some information (like the file) and then calls [`RenameLinkedMode`](https://github.com/xored/yang-ide/blob/7cab25b5ff8ce71e5b33b68b692dfb386404f995/plugins/com.cisco.yangide.ext.refactoring/src/com/cisco/yangide/ext/refactoring/ui/RenameLinkedMode.java) to do the work.

The call to `RenameSupport.findLocalReferences()` seems most promising as the source of your bug.

A note about debugging: You can try to add logging to the plugin to see what it does when debugging is too complicated.

Or you can try [chronon](http://chrononsystems.com/) which allows you to record the program execution and step forward and backward in time or answer questions like "where did this value come from?"

Comment: Thanks.  I've somehow managed to corrupt my workspace, so I'll have to fix this first before I can try any of these.

Comment: Just the lead for RenameSupport was enough.  I found the place where it wasn't checking references carefully enough and implemented an initial solution.  Now that I have a working remote debug process in place, things like this will be a little easier.